# Angular directive get values from NgModel or FormControlName

Tags: angular, compatibility, directive

I have a directive that checks if the form component was create using Reactive Forms or a Template-Driven. I use that to maintain the compatibility between other components that use the same directive. All works very fine in Angular 8, but not in Angular 9.

Inside my directive I have a method to get and set the field value, to set the filed status dirty or touched but to do that, I have a conditional to know what the form was used by the component.

Unfortunately in Angular 9, I couldn't do that because I don't know how to do that. Please, if someone could help me, I appreciate it.

Bellow my directive

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelect2Cities]',
})
export class Select2CitiesDirective implements OnChanges, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit {
  input: any;

  // Cast one of the types to a variable
  @ContentChild(NgModel, { static: false }) model: NgModel;
  @ContentChild(FormControlName, { static: false }) control: FormControlName;

  // ... some code here

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.model) {
      // ... some code here
    } else if (this.control) {
      // ... some code here
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.input = this.model || this.control;

    if (this.input === undefined) { // <-- Always undefined here
      throw new Error('That directive needs to be used by ngModel or FormControlName');
    }

    this.initializeSelect2();
  }
    
  // ... some code here
}
```

A sample when I'm using Reactive Forms

```html
<select
  appSelect2Cities
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="cities"
  [value]="citiesValue"
  placeholder="Select a City"
  (itemSelected)="onCitySelected($event)"
>
</select>
```

and a sample when I'm using a Template-Driven

```html
<select
  appSelect2Cities
  class="form-control"
  name="city"
  [(ngModel)]="address.city"
>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found an answer to my problem!

I don't know exactly why `@ContentChild` doesn't work the same way in this case, but I believe that it has to do with the changes made by the Angular team to fix buggy and surprising behaviour in queries. See that  https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

The solution in my case was just to declare the `NgModel` and `FormControlName` inside the constructor instead to use the `@ContentChild`, like below

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelect2Cities]',
})
export class Select2CitiesDirective implements OnChanges, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit {
  input: any;

  constructor(@Optional() private model: NgModel, @Optional() private control: FormControlName) {}

  // ... some code here

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.model) {
      // ... some code here
    } else if (this.control) {
      // ... some code here
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.input = this.model || this.control;

    if (this.input === undefined) { // <-- Now works fine
      throw new Error('That directive needs to be used by ngModel or FormControlName');
    }

    this.initializeSelect2();
  }
    
  // ... some code here
}
```

Comment: You can also inject **only** [NgControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl#subclasses) : `constructor(@Optional() @Host() private control:NgControl){}`. When you have ngModel or formControl or formControlName, in "control" you have the "input"